# Plotting equations in R

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2

I recently saw this image, and wanted to emulate these plots in `R`.

[image: equations]

However, being more of a "data-wrangler" than a mathematician, I'm not sure how to do this. Ideally, I would like to use `ggplot2`. I managed the first example (the 'L'), but then got stuck:

```
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(data.frame(x = c(1, 100)), aes(x = x)) + 
  stat_function(fun = function(x){1/x}, geom = 'line')
```

[image]

The ideal answer would use `ggplot2`, and would make a `facet_wrap` of the images to plot them in a square arrangement

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A start with facets:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)

L <- data_frame(x = 1:100,
                y = 1 / x)
O <- data_frame(t = seq(-pi, pi, l = 100),
                x = 3 * cos(t),
                y = 3 * sin(t))
V <- data_frame(x = -50:50,
                y = abs(-2 * x))
E <- data_frame(y = seq(-pi, pi, l = 100),
                x = -3 * abs(sin(y)))
pd <- bind_rows(L = L, O = O, V = V, E = E, .id = 'letter')

pd$letter <- factor(pd$letter, 
                    c('L', 'O', 'V', 'E'),
                    c('y == 1/x', 'x^2 + y^2 == 9', 'y == abs(-2*x)', 'x == -3*abs(sin(y))'))

ggplot(pd, aes(x, y)) +
  geom_vline(xintercept = 0) + geom_hline(yintercept = 0) +
  geom_path(size = 1.5, col = 'red') +
  facet_wrap(~letter, scales = 'free', labeller = label_parsed) +
  theme_minimal() +
  theme(axis.text = element_blank(), axis.title = element_blank(),
        panel.grid = element_blank())
ggsave('LOVE.png', w = 3.5, h = 4, dpi = 300)
```

[image]

Comment: Great job, and very easy to follow what you've done here. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
 library(ggplot2)
title <- textGrob(expression(bold('ALL YOU NEED IS')), gp = gpar(fontsize = 36))
p1.text <- ggplot() + 
  annotate("text", x=10, y=40, label='italic(y == frac(1,x))', parse=TRUE, size=8) +
  theme_bw() +
  theme(axis.text = element_blank(), axis.title = element_blank(),
        panel.border = element_blank(),
        panel.grid = element_blank(),
        axis.ticks=element_blank())

p1.curve <- ggplot(data.frame(x = c(1, 50)), aes(x = x)) + 
  stat_function(fun = function(x){1/x}, geom = 'line', col='red', lwd=2) + 
  geom_hline(yintercept=0, col='gray50') + 
  geom_vline(xintercept=0, col='gray50') + 
  theme_bw() +
  theme(axis.text = element_blank(), axis.title = element_blank(),
        panel.border = element_blank(),
        panel.grid = element_blank(),
        axis.ticks=element_blank())

p2.text <-  ggplot() + 
  annotate("text", x=10, y=40, label="italic(x^2+y^2==9)", parse=TRUE, size=8) +
  theme_bw() +
  theme(axis.text = element_blank(), axis.title = element_blank(),
        panel.border = element_blank(),
        panel.grid = element_blank(),
        axis.ticks=element_blank())

p2.curve <- ggplot(data.frame(theta = seq(-10, 10, .01)), aes(x = 3*cos(theta), y = 3*sin(theta))) + 
  geom_point(col='red') + theme_bw() + 
  geom_hline(yintercept=0, col='gray50') + 
  geom_vline(xintercept=0, col='gray50') + 
  theme_bw() +
  theme(axis.text = element_blank(), axis.title = element_blank(),
        panel.border = element_blank(),
        panel.grid = element_blank(),
        axis.ticks=element_blank())

p3.text <-  ggplot() + 
  annotate("text", x=10, y=40, label="italic(y)==abs(-italic(2*x))", parse=TRUE, size=8) +
  theme_bw() +
  theme(axis.text = element_blank(), axis.title = element_blank(),
        panel.border = element_blank(),
        panel.grid = element_blank(),
        axis.ticks=element_blank())

p3.curve <- ggplot(data.frame(x = c(-25, 25)), aes(x = x)) + 
  stat_function(fun = function(x){abs(-2*x)}, geom = 'line', col='red', lwd=2) + 
  geom_hline(yintercept=0, col='gray50') + 
  geom_vline(xintercept=0, col='gray50') + 
  theme_bw() +
  theme(axis.text = element_blank(), axis.title = element_blank(),
        panel.border = element_blank(),
        panel.grid = element_blank(),
        axis.ticks=element_blank())

p4.text <-  ggplot() + 
  annotate("text", x=10, y=40, label="x==-italic(3)*abs(italic(sin(y)))", parse=TRUE, size=8) +
  theme_bw() +
  theme(axis.text = element_blank(), axis.title = element_blank(),
        panel.border = element_blank(),
        panel.grid = element_blank(),
        axis.ticks=element_blank())

p4.curve <- ggplot(data.frame(x = c(-3.2, 3.2)), aes(x = x)) + 
  stat_function(fun = function(x){-3*abs(sin(x))}, geom = 'line', col='red', lwd=2) + 
  coord_flip() + 
  geom_hline(yintercept=0, col='gray50') + 
  geom_vline(xintercept=0, col='gray50') + 
  theme_bw() +
  theme(axis.text = element_blank(), axis.title = element_blank(),
        panel.border = element_blank(),
        panel.grid = element_blank(),
        axis.ticks=element_blank())

library(grid)
library(gridExtra)
grid.arrange(title, p1.text,p1.curve, p2.text, p2.curve, p3.text, p3.curve, p4.text, p4.curve, ncol=2,
             layout_matrix = matrix(c(1,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9), ncol=2, byrow=TRUE))
```

[image]

Comment: This is also a great answer - very clearly explained and lovely result - I wish I could accept both! I've gone with @Axeman because I think he pipped you in timing and managed the `facet_wrap` challenge

Comment: @JonnyPolonsky: I did not use facet it's true, since i thought the goal was to just draw the curves, but I think I submitted first :), changed it a little more to fit to your rquirement.